# Borrar Dato Jquery Al Abrir Otra Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Tengo una sencilla tabla, el cual al oprimir un botón me toma ese id de la fila y hace un envió a `php` el cual el le retorna todos los valores por un `JSON`
y me los muestra en una ventana emergente, en este caso me muestra un nombre, el problema es que cuando voy abrir una ventana emergente de otra fila me aparece el nombre de la fila anterior y el nombre de la ventana que acabo de abrir.

Es como si se acumulara los nombre uno por uno cada vez que abro una ventana emergente diferente

Este es el código que estoy utilizando.

```
$("#nombre").append(answer[0].nombre);
```

Si uso un `remove();` ps no me muestra el dato en pantalla entonces creería que no me funciona este método.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso es porque estás utilizando `append` que es algo así como añadir. 
Es por ello que se está concatenando.
Deberías utilizar `text`:

```
$("#nombre").text(answer[0].nombre);
```

Comment: Te agradezco eso no lo sabia.